# Adding a cronjob into cPanel

Tags: cron, cpanel

I just need to run the following url using cron jobs in my cPanel.

When I am trying to execute the link

http://www.insidewealth.com.au/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron

the link is running in browser but when I am tried to add the same URL as it is in cron jobs I am getting the following error

`bash/sh/ file not found`

and when I edited the cron job as

`/usr/bin/php /home/staging/public_html/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron`

but I am getting 404 error.

My cPanel username is `staging`

Can anybody tell me what's the syntax of cron job in cPanel.

Cron Job running every minute and email report showing this errors.

Comment: Can you check cPanel file manager and confirm the path to index.php is /home/staging/public_html/ ?

Comment: @sinisterfrog - Yeah, the file is in right location.

Comment: Also check the route of php by typing `which php`.

Answer (score 0):

Use wget function with full URL.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

@yannick-blondeau As suggested **you can use a wget or curl** to make a simple request to your website.

Usually wget will attempt to download a file but this is not necessary with the `-O` flag to pipe to `/dev/null` or `-q` (both options used to prevent from saving output to a file), an example will look like

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.insidewealth.com.au/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron
wget -q http://www.insidewealth.com.au/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron
```

You can also use curl for the same effect

```
curl --silent http://www.insidewealth.com.au/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron
```